# What does it mean to be 'debonair'?

Tags: meaning

***Debonair*** seems to me to have disappeared from current English, and perhaps belongs in an age when they made films like *Gone With the Wind*.

Is it that the word has ceased to exist, and if so what is its modern equivalent?

Or do the *debonair* no longer exist? Is it simply unfashionable to be *debonair*, whatever that was?

Who in modern society might be described as *debonair*?

Comment: It hasn't disappeared from current spoken English in my experience—it's just not that common. It's definitely something I've heard a fairly broad selection of people using in normal, daily conversation on occasion.

Comment: It's certainly still used, though usually in a jocular sense.  If someone comes to work all dressed up I might say, "Gee, you're looking really de-BONE-er this morning."

Comment: @HotLicks But that's an ironic use of the term - a bit like calling someone Squire - isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Being a term that was used mainly to refer to the courteous and charming qualities of a gentlemen,  it is more   typical of a  'Downton Abbey' kind of society. I think it  is understandable  that its usage has decreased in recent decades. Anyway the term appears to be still alive in current romantic literature. According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=debonair&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdebonair%3B%2Cc0) (debonair):

[Debonair](https://www.etymonline.com/word/debonair): etymology

> - c.1200, "mild, gentle, kind courteous," from Old French debonaire, from de bon' aire "of good race," originally used of hawks, hence, "thoroughbred" (opposite of French demalaire). Used in Middle English to mean "docile, courteous," it became obsolete and was revived with an altered sense of "pleasant, affable" (1680s).

[Debonair](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/debonair):

> - courteous, gracious, and having a sophisticated charm:
>
>   - a debonair gentleman.

- Affable and gentle may be common terms that may be used to indicate   the qualities that debonair refers to.

Comment: In colloquial usages at least, I have mostly heard the other sense of the word, “jaunty, carefree, sprightly”, with a hint of rich-boy superiority about it—in other words, a certain amount of condescension connoted into the word. _Affable_ and _gentle_ are not very suitable for that usage.

Comment: Yes some of Lady Mary's suitors are undoubtedly *debonair*. Which suggests to me that not just the word but the figure himself (he was usually male) has disappeared. I note you didn't attempt to say who, in today's society might be *debonair*.

Comment: @WS2 - can't think of any at the moment...

Comment: @Josh61 No, nor could I. I just think it is such an unfashionable image that the word has almost disappeared because of redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

Bond, James Bond.

Agent 007 seems to me to be the walking definition of the word debonair, and they're still making Bond movies.  No matter who's playing the secret agent, he's always debonair.

Comment: It is certainly worth an upvote. But JB was of course created by Iain Fleming as far back as 1952 (*Casino Royale*). His creator undoubtedly bore the pre-war image of *debonair*, son of the Merchant Bank family of Fleming & Co, and with his *Eton* and *Sandhurst* education. Fleming inhabited possibly the very age when being *debonair* was at its peak, especially the wartime years. Sadly James Bond is a bit dated now, and he sits rather awkwardly in our feminist society.

Comment: Ian Fleming, creator of Bondo-san! http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/fe/Ian_Fleming%2C_headshot.jpg/300px-Ian_Fleming%2C_headshot.jpg

Comment: Craig is not debonair. He is an aggressive bastard :/

Answer (score 0):

It's still in use here in France, although without "suave" connotations, but signifying someone good natured.  *Le Robert dictionnaire de la langue française*

Comment: I'm sure it is still used in France, but this does not answer the OP's main question: **Is it that the word has ceased to exist, and if so what is its modern equivalent?**

Answer (score 0):

"Debonair" is still part of the language but is now dated. The nearest equivalent in modern usage is probably *cool*.

The [Collins Online Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cool) gives this definition (number 9) among others for cool:

> **adjective** If you say that a person or their behaviour is cool, you mean that they are fashionable and attractive.
>   Synonyms: fashionable, with it, hip, stylish

Which makes it a match for *debonair* by the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/debonair) definition which reads

> (especially of men) attractive, confident and carefully dressed

"Cool" isn't really a synonym for "debonair" as a)it has other meanings and b)in its slang meaning it can be applied to products, music, experiences and many other things which could never have been described as "debonair", but it is used currently to describe people in much the same way as "debonair" used to be employed.

Answer (score 0):

urbane is a choice that would replace the much less used debonair

**urbane**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/urbane)

> Polite, refined, and often elegant in manner.

[image: urbane and debonair ngram]

Comment: I don’t think I’ve ever heard *urbane* used in conversation.